# Is it possible to make a merge in one command without committing and modifying the index?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Let's say that I've got some cool tool for development and I keep it on a branch called 'tool'. My product has many customizations and hence there are many branches used for development. Despite the fact that the tool is so groovy, I don't want to commit them to any other branch.

When I need the tool on some development branch, I use git in the following way:
`git merge --no-commit tool

git reset`

With the above I get all the files I need to my current branch and I clean my index.

The question is whether this is achievable in one command? Maybe there's some other good way to use git for my scenario? I've got to say that I don't like `git stash` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in `git` to perform these two actions in one command, but you could combine them using `bash` by running it as:

```
git merge --no-commit tool && git reset
```

You could even alias that to something short, like `alias gtool="git merge ..."` and then just run `gtool`.

Comment: Thanks, that's also quite useful, although I wish you were wrong about git being unable to do the job 'with one bullet' :)

Comment: For the alias, you need to prepend it with `!`. You might also want to use the first parameter as the branch that's passed to `gtool`: `git config --global alias.gtool '!git merge $1 && git reset'`

Comment: @AlexanderGroß, The `!` you're talking about is for git aliases, while I was referring to bash aliases.